# Happiness Cross Sectional Data

Tags: data-request

Looking for a data set that attempts to measure happiness, welfare, and security. Ideally at an individual level across countries and or states. Thanks for any help you are provide.

Comment: http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/world%20values%20survey%20%28wvs%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you mean with "happiness, welfare, and security" but the Life in transition survey (http://www.ebrd.com/what-we-do/economic-research-and-data/data/lits.html) has several possibly related questions including "How satisfied are you with your life", and exists in two waves with relatively big samples